# Error installing facebook/graph-sdk with composer 1.5.2 on XAMPP PHP 7.0.3 on ubuntu 14.0.4 lts

Tags: codeigniter, xampp, composer-php, facebook-php-sdk, php-7

I have xampp with php 7.0.3 installed on ubuntu 14.04 lts.

I installed composer globally (version: 1.5.2 2017-09-11 16:59:25)

In my codeigniter project I want to use the Facebook SDK, but it won't work unless I install the Graph SDK.

So I did the following:

```
$ composer show --all facebook/graph-sdk

name     : facebook/graph-sdk
descrip. : Facebook SDK for PHP
keywords : facebook, sdk
versions : dev-master, 6.x-dev, 5.x-dev, 5.6.1, 5.6.0, 5.5.x-dev, 5.5.0, 5.4.x-dev, 5.4.4, 5.4.3, 5.4.2, 5.4.1, 5.4.0, 5.3.x-dev, 5.3.1, 5.3.0, 5.2.x-dev, 5.2.1, 5.2.0, 5.1.x-dev, 5.1.5, 5.1.4, 5.1.3, 5.1.2, 5.1.1, 5.1.0, 5.0.0, 4.0.23, 4.0.22, 4.0.21, 4.0.20, 4.0.19, 4.0.18, 4.0.17, 4.0.16, 4.0.15, 4.0.14, 4.0.13, 4.0.12, 4.0.11, 4.0.10, 4.0.9, 4.0.8, 4.0.7, 4.0.6, 4.0.5, 4.0.4, 4.0.3, 4.0.2, 4.0.1, v4.0.0, dev-4.1-dev, dev-4.0-dev
type     : library
license  : Facebook Platform
source   : [git] https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk.git 6bb017aa3d4b24852a619a8f00340cfe2a34f6cc
dist     : [zip] https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/php-graph-sdk/zipball/6bb017aa3d4b24852a619a8f00340cfe2a34f6cc 6bb017aa3d4b24852a619a8f00340cfe2a34f6cc
names    : facebook/graph-sdk

autoload
psr-4
Facebook\ => src/

requires
php ^7.1
psr/http-message ^1.0
php-http/client-implementation ^1.0
php-http/httplug ^1.0
php-http/discovery ^1.0
php-http/message ^1.0

requires (dev)
phpunit/phpunit ^6.2
php-http/guzzle6-adapter ^1.0

$ composer require facebook/graph-sdk
Using version ^5.6 for facebook/graph-sdk
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package facebook/graph-sdk No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by facebook/graph-sdk[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

These lines seem to imply that v 5.6 of facebook/graph-sdk needs php 7.1 or higher:

```
requires
php ^7.1
...
Using version ^5.6 for facebook/graph-sdk
```

Is my conclusion correct, or is the error something completely different?

My issue is that *I cannot upgrade php to 7.1 easily* as it might break a lot of code in production in a huge application.

So what options do I have? As far as my googling tells me:

1. I can use the manual method of installing the Facebook Graph SDK from https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/5.x/docs/getting_started.md#manually-installing-if-you-really-have-to and hope that I do not have to run the code that needs the PHP 7.1 changes.
2. I might be able to coax composer into using a version of the facebook/graph-sdk package that works with php 7.0 rather than 7.1. I don't know how to do that yet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit - *The composer.json file here https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/5.x/composer.json does not show php7.1 as a requirement. It says "php": "^5.4|^7.0". How can I tell composer to use this version, so as to see if this is really the source of the error?*

Anything else I can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems composer tries to install 5.6 version and if you look at this file https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/master/composer.json PHP 7.1 is required for this version.

If you want to use it with PHP 7.0 try to install previous 5.5 version:

```
composer require facebook/graph-sdk:5.5.*
```

but it's possible 5.5 version might conflict with other packages you have already installed

Comment: thanks for the superfast reply. I've been trying for a few hours since and fixed other composer issues I had, but no luck yet. Will post with details when I succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes disregarding lots of details and choosing the easy way is better, try :

$ composer install

If your composer.json file already has :

> "name": "facebook/graph-sdk",

Then you don't need the :

> composer require facebook/graph-sdk

Even though it's in the actual Github doc for the Facebook SDK for PHP!

Remember, I had exactly the same error you had...
You're really trying to do too much in this case. As a coder of course we like that, usually that is right. But it's composer's job to adjust dependencies, not your job. If you're still not convinced, read on.

After I installed facebook/graph-sdk with PHP 7.0.33 (on my local machine, not in the composer.json file), composer created a "composer.lock" file with this :

```
"require": {
                "php": ">=5.3,<8.0-DEV"
            },
```

But I was curious to see if it would work with PHP 7.3.3 on my machine. It also worked. I reinstalled composer using PHP 7.3.3. I removed the "vendor" folder and the "composer.lock" file. I did "composer clear-cache" just to make sure everything was clean. Used another command shell, it gave me a new "composer.lock" file with this :

```
"require": {
                "php": "^7.1"
            },
```

You see? Composer adjusts the requirements depending on your system. All I had to do was

> composer install

in both cases.